# Video chat between libjingle based client and gtalk

Tags: webrtc, videochat, libjingle, google-hangouts

I've a got a libjingle based google talk client (call application) built and i'm trying to call to gtalk (talk available as part of gmail web client).

Unfortunately i don't see a video and audio of libjingle based client on the gtalk, but the video and audio of gtalk is seen on the libjingle based client.

Video chat was working very fine some time back. I suspect that after google rolled out or updated the gmail client with hangout feature something has changed with respect to protocol or some hand shaking mechanism which might not be compatible.

Any thoughts or ideas on this ??